# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Scaffold Identity - CSS/Layout now ignored

Tags: asp.net

I have done the suggested scaffold operation to create the Identity source folders in my MVC 2.1 application. Prior the Bootstrap 4 CSS was working fine. Now, after the scaffold, it seems to be ignoring it and I can't figure out why.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Without pasting your code, it is hard to figure out which "suggested" scaffold operation you have carried out. Note that ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured this out. Not sure why I didn't check this before, but I copied the Bootstrap 4 CSS and JS files to the wrong folder. Now that they are in the correct place, the CSS is working.